# Why does the cowboy stab the woman in Unforgiven?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, clint-eastwood, unforgiven

In [Unforgiven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105695/),Why does the **cowboy stab the woman** in the beginning of the movie?

Was he crazy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The woman is one of the younger prostitutes, working from the tavern.  She upsets the cowboy by laughing at him - specifically giggling at his size.

When talking to Little Bill after the attack, Alice (the unofficial leader of the girls) says:

> She's going to live. She didn't steal nothing.
> She didn't even touch his poke. Alls she done, when she
> seen he has a teensy little pecker, is give a giggle. That's all.
> She didn't know no better. Going to hang them, Little Bill?

(from [a transcript script](http://www.clinteastwood.net/filmography/unforgiven/script/unforgivenscript.txt), There is also also a pretty similar wording from [David People's script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/unforgiven.html).)

Its hinted that she is less experienced than the other girls ('she didn't know no better').

Comment: That's not a script, it's a transcript. This would work better; https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/unforgiven.html

Comment: Thanks - added. But in what way does that work better?

Comment: Because transcripts are usually fan-written and subject to error.

Comment: Unfortunately scripts are often rewritten, or not shot or edited as written and subject to error.

Comment: Sure, but labeling something as a script when it's not a script isn't helpful either.

Answer (score 5):

It was mentioned in the film that woman had said something unflattering about the size of the cowboy's 'equipment'. This angered him and he cut her up.